# Problem with createAsyncThunk callBack function arguments

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

Why is it that when I throw email and password into dispatch. In createAsyncThunk callBack function arguments, my password turns into an unknown object. For post i use axios.

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { loginAuth } from '@/features/auth/authSlice'

export function Auth() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    function handleVisibility() {
        setIsVisible(!isVisible)
    }

    function onSubmit() {
        debugger
        dispatch(loginAuth(email, password))
    }
```

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { login, registration, logout } from '@/shared/api/AuthService'

export const loginAuth = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/loginAuth',
    async (email, password) => {
        try {
            debugger
            const response = await login(email, password)
            const data = await response.json()
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
)
```

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gszZj.png)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA4yU.png)

I expected get password as password, and not as object